# Lock Voice Channel After Creating It (Discord Python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to lock the voice channel so that nobody can join it after creating it. The voice channel is being used as a server clock. Here are the codes where the channel is being created:

```
        for channel in saved_guild["guild"].channels:
            #first_word = channel.name.split(" ")[0]
            #if first_word == ' (GMT-4)':
            if ' (GMT-4)' in channel.name:
                await channel.delete()
                #channel_exists = True
                #await channel.edit(name=new_title)
                #break

        #create new channel
        if not channel_exists:
            await saved_guild["guild"].create_voice_channel(new_title)
```

And

```
channel_exists = False
for channel in context.guild.channels:
    #first_word = channel.name.split(" ")[0]
    #if first_word == 'Time/Hora':
    if ' (GMT-4)' in channel.name:
        await channel.delete()
        #channel_exists = True
        #await channel.edit(name=new_title)
        #break

#create new channel
if not channel_exists:
    await context.guild.create_voice_channel(new_title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion made by yotam rec helped, this was the new code:

```
for channel in saved_guild["guild"].channels:
            if '' in channel.name:
                await channel.set_permissions(saved_guild["guild"].roles[0], connect=True)
                await channel.delete()
```

and

```
if not channel_exists:
            await saved_guild["guild"].create_voice_channel(new_title)
            for channel in saved_guild["guild"].channels:
                if '' in channel.name:
                   await channel.set_permissions(saved_guild["guild"].roles[0], connect=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock the voice channel for EVERYBODY, you could so something like this:

```
for channel in ctx.guild.voice_channels:
  #insert code here
  for role, permissions in channel.overwrites:
    permissions.connect = False
    await channel.set_permissions(role, permissions)
```

This basically denies "connect" perms for every role in the voice channels permissions list

Comment: Hi, this seems to not work, here are the codes:
 
`for channel in saved_guild["guild"].channels:
                if ' (GMT-4)' in channel.name:
                    for role, permissions in channel.overwrites:
                        permissions.connect = False
                        await channel.set_permissions(role, permissions)`

and

`for channel in context.channels:
        if ' (GMT-4)' in channel.name:
            for role, permissions in channel.overwrites:
                permissions.connect = False
                await channel.set_permissions(role, permissions)`

Comment: @rmbettencourt What do you mean `seems to not work`? What doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: It does not lock the channel, there are no errors thrown.

Comment: I can offer you to start by trying to do it just for @everyone with this
await currant_voice_channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.roles[0], connect=False)
await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} the channel has been locked down")